# Is there any way to call unknown methods of a template argument class?

Tags: c++, class, templates

I once implemented a state machine like this:

```
class Player
{
public:
    int Run();
    int Jump();
    int Stop();

private:
    class State
    {
    public:
        virtual int Run() = 0;
        virtual int Jump() = 0;
        virtual int Stop() = 0;
    };

    class StandingState : public State
    {
        virtual int Run() { /*...*/ }
        virtual int Jump() { /*...*/ }
        virtual int Stop() { /*...*/ }
    };

    class RunningState : public State
    {
        virtual int Run() { /*...*/ }
        virtual int Jump() { /*...*/ }
        virtual int Stop() { /*...*/ }
    };

    // More states go here!

    std::list<State*> states;
    State* currentState;
};

int Player::Run()
{
    int result = m_currentState->Run();

    // do something with result
}

int Player::Jump()
{
    int result = m_currentState->Jump();

    // do something with result
}

int Player::Stop()
{
    int result = m_currentState->Stop();

    // do something with result
}
```

Fairly textbook I should think: `Player` delegates the calls from outside to its current `State` object, and does something with the result (possibly transitioning to another state). Essentially, each state knows how a given action affects it, but it's up to the state machine to wire the various states together. I found this to be a good separation of concerns.

But I'm seeing a possibility for abstraction here. The entire system is defined by the interface of the `State` class:

1. Both the state machine and the substates implement `State`
2. The state machine keeps a pointer to all possible `State`s and the current `State`
3. Whatever method of `State` is called on the state machine, it is undiscerningly forwarded to the current state.

So, we can totally make this a class template, right? Look:

```
template< class StateInterface >
class StateMachine : public StateInterface
{
    // public methods already declared in StateInterface

protected:
    std::list<StateInterface*> states;
    void AddState(StateInterface* state);
    StateInterface* currentState;
};

class PlayerStateInterface
{
public:
    virtual int Run() = 0;
    virtual int Jump() = 0;
    virtual int Stop() = 0;
};

class Player : public StateMachine< PlayerStateInterface >
{
public:    
    virtual int Run() { currentState->Run(); /* do stuff */ }
    virtual int Jump() { currentState->Jump(); /* do stuff */ }
    virtual int Stop() { currentState->Stop(); /* do stuff */ }
};
```

Of the above points, this has 1 and 2 covered, but what about 3? I still have to manually delegate the calls to the current state in the concrete state machine implementation. Is there a way to move that functionality to the `StateMachine` template? Can I somehow express that whenever a method of `StateInterface` is called on `StateMachine` it should call the same method on `currentState`, when I don't know the names or signatures of `StateInterface`'s methods?

Comment: You might be interested to have a look at [STTCL](http://makulik.github.io/sttcl/)- I've designed it using exactly that principle. (Sorry some drawbacks: Interface methods (events), need to be known by the top level and sub-state machines)

Comment: I guess `StandingState` and `RunningState` derive from `State` in the first code block?

Comment: @DyP: Bloops! Quite right, edited. Thanks.

Comment: It's not very clear what exactly you are trying to do. Pretend the compiler can understand anything a human programmer can, any fantastic language construct you want (not "solve this problem for me" kind, obviously). How would your code look then? Please be more specific than "do stuff", as it's not clear whether "stuff" is supposed to be the same or different.

Comment: @n.m. The "do stuff" part is unimportant. At the moment, the only way I can make a concrete `StateMachine` class forward calls to its state object is by having it implement all of `StateInterface`'s methods. I'm asking if there's a way to make the `StateMachine` template itself do the call forwarding. Basically, I want to tell the compiler to define each method `M` of `StateMachine` as `M() { currentState->M(); }`. Or at least those methods that are defined in `StateInterface`.

Comment: You can't do a state machine this way. You need to transition between states somehow.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a general answer to the case where `Run`, `Jump`, and `Stop` have different signatures, I don't know if there's a good solution. However, in your example they all have the same signature, which suggests to me that the following approach might work:

```
#include <iostream>

class AbstractState
{
public:
    virtual void write1() = 0;
    virtual void write2() = 0;
};

class State1: public AbstractState
{
public:
    virtual void write1() { std::cout << "1-1" << std::endl; }
    virtual void write2() { std::cout << "1-2" << std::endl; }
};

class State2: public AbstractState
{
public:
    virtual void write1() { std::cout << "2-1" << std::endl; }
    virtual void write2() { std::cout << "2-2" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename StateInterface>
class Player
{
public:
    Player(StateInterface *s_):
        s(s_)
    {
    }

    void setState(StateInterface *s_)
    {
        s = s_;
    }

    void execute(void (StateInterface::*method)())
    {
        (s->*method)();
    }
private:
    StateInterface *s;
};

int main()
{
    State1 s1;
    State2 s2;

    Player<AbstractState> p(&s1);

    p.execute(&AbstractState::write1);
    p.execute(&AbstractState::write2);

    p.setState(&s2);

    p.execute(&AbstractState::write1);
    p.execute(&AbstractState::write2);

    return 0;
}
```

I was able to compile and run this with GCC 4.5.2 and got the expected result, namely:

```
1-1
1-2
2-1
2-2
```

As I said, I'm not sure that there's a good way to extend this to the case where the different member functions of `AbstractState` take different parameters or return different values, and there may be other drawbacks that I haven't considered yet. It isn't quite as nice as what I think you were hoping to find, but hopefully this will at least serve as a good starting point.